# Way to set credentials in HttpClient after made a wrapper for it in C#

Tags: c#

I create an interface called `INetClient` which supports two clients: `HttpClient` and `WebClient` ( I want that my app to be unit-testable)

The interface looks like:

```
public interface INetClient
{
    ...

    void SetCredentials(ICredentials credentials);

    void SetHeaders(Dictionary<HttpRequestHeader, string> headers);

    void SetHeaders(Dictionary<string, string> headers);

    ...
}
```

For each of them, I created a wrapper class which implements that interface.

For web client, I did like:

```
public sealed class WebClientEx : WebClient, INetClient
{   
    public WebClientEx()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    }

    public void SetCredentials(ICredentials credentials)
    {
        Credentials = credentials;
    }
}
```

and for http client:

```
public sealed class HttpClientEx : INetClient, IDisposable
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public HttpClientEx()
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        _client = new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    public void SetCredentials(ICredentials credentials)
    {           
        // here, how I can set credentials ?
    }
}
```

Later on I will use dependency injection like `RegisterType<INetClient, WebClientEx>` or I can change easily to `RegisterType<INetClient, HttpClientEx>`

How can set credentials for http client without creating new instance for it ?

Comment: is there a reason, why you want to use 2 different web clients - which are doing pretty the same thing?

Comment: I have two apps (one old and one mobile app where I will use httpclient because webclient is not supported) and I unify by using a core library ... and then do unit tests

Comment: Make HttpClientEx not inherit from HttpClient. Instead, wrap an HttpClient. You can then manage instances of HttpClient however you like. Inheritance is the wrong solution here anyway. I'd also remove the set methods and make that data an argument to the method that sends the request. No need for mutable state.

Comment: I agree with @usr.  You are essentially creating the Adapter pattern.  An adapter doesn't inherit from the things it is adapting.

Comment: I don't inherit anything from `HttpClient`, it implements two interfaces

Comment: @usr: My question still remains ...

Comment: I did not see that. OK, so does your question reduce to "How to set credentials per request with HTTP client?" If yes I suggest you delete everything else from the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your web service is using HTTP Basic authentication, you could set the header using the [`HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property